# How i can get values order by the count of distinct values

Tags: mysql, magento2

I want to get those Product in ascending order who number is greater in mysql

```
  order_id    |     product_id    
     1        |         13    
     1        |         12    
     1        |         24    
     2        |         14    
     2        |         245    
     2        |         23    
     3        |         14    
     3        |         23    
     4        |         14
```

i have done that code but its not working

```
SELECT  product_id  FROM `sales_order_item`  ORDER BY COUNT('product_id') ASC
```

i want priduct_id in ascending order on the basis of there count\

```
product_id
    14
    23
    13
    24
    245
```

as 14 occurs 4 times it must have to be on top and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `order by COUNT('product_id') desc`

```
SELECT  product_id,COUNT('product_id') as cnt  FROM `sales_order_item` 
group by product_id 
ORDER BY cnt desc
```

Comment: `Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query`